# Struts2 time (HH:mm) mapping to action field

Tags: datetime, struts2

I have a simple struts2 from:

```
<s:form ...>
<s:textfield name="initialTime" maxlength="5" size="5" />
</s:form>
```

Where the user has to enter a time in HH:mm format.  In the corresponding Action, I have a property:

```
private Date initialTime;
```

along with its getter/setter.

I am getting a validation problem, as the received initialTime (i.e. 10:20) is not understood as a valid Date.

What is the good approach to retrieve times ?  Should I use a `private String initialTime` field instead of a `Date` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to change the property to a String and programatically transform it to whatever final format you want. 
While I may see cases where the conversion from HH:mm to a Date may make sense, I think we can agree this is not a general scenario.

./alex